# How do i cover this test class declaration?

Tags: unit-test

I have written a test class for my apex class and was able to cover all the lines except these three lines

HO do i cover this?

Apex class:

[image]

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class Test_GNWAVMService  {


    static testMethod void testPostWithEmptyBody() {

        system.Debug('======= START testPostWithEmptyBody =======');                

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/GNWDocument/';
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof('');
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        GNWAVMService avm = new GNWAVMService();
        GNWGlobalTypes.GNWStatusResponse reponse = GNWAVMService.doPost();

        system.debug('===== EMPTY POST RESPONSE: ' + reponse.wsResponse.wmstatus + ' , ' + reponse.wsResponse.wmmessage);


        system.assertEquals('error',reponse.wsResponse.wmstatus);    


        system.Debug('======= END testPostWithEmptyBody =======');  

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a new method and there provide some data in

```
req.requestBody = Blob.valueof('xyz');
```

---

```
static testMethod void testPostWithBody() {

        system.Debug('======= START testPostWithEmptyBody =======');                

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/GNWDocument/';
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof('expected response data');
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        GNWAVMService avm = new GNWAVMService();
        GNWGlobalTypes.GNWStatusResponse reponse = GNWAVMService.doPost();

        system.debug('===== EMPTY POST RESPONSE: ' + reponse.wsResponse.wmstatus + ' , ' + reponse.wsResponse.wmmessage);


        system.assertEquals('error',reponse.wsResponse.wmstatus);    


        system.Debug('======= END testPostWithEmptyBody =======');  

    }
```

Comment: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2] --- i am getting this as error when i try to run the test class

Comment: @Azeem in responseBody provide the real json string. The test I wrote is for example only as I don't know what is the response body you are processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **HttpCalloutMock** interface to test the webservice or external httpcallout.

[Click here for detail information](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)

Thanks,
Prakash